# Section of Data frame changes not applied

Tags: python, pandas

I have a 1.7 million line txt file that I received. I am using pandas to prepare the file to upload to PostgreSQL server. It is pipe-delimited and has || and '\ ' for null values which works fine. I change the one column to an int which works.  I load the file into a dataframe everything works until about line 1265821. Starting at this line the file changes. The column whose data type I changed to int has decimals again. The null values of \ which I removed reappear. This last until line 1268801 where all the changes I made appear again.

I have changed the delimiter several times to see if that is causing a problem. I have tried `df.replace('\ ', '')` and `df.replace('\\ ', '')` instead of using it as a na value in the read_csv.

```py
headers2=[headers list]
df=pd.read_csv('/Volumes/SCANS/data_request_2008_2018copy.txt',sep='|',index_col=False,names=headers2,na_values='\\ ',dtype= {'Casenumber':object,'ChargeSerialNumber':object,'Complaintnumber':'int'})
df.to_csv('/Volumes/SCANS/wholetestupload2.txt',index=False, sep='|')
```

I need to know why this is happening. I will be getting more data from this same source and would like to avoid having to manually process these files in the future.

Comment: add dummy txt data similar to yours in OP to reproduce your issue, to let others help you better.

Comment: may be your dataset has leading or trailing spaces

Comment: 3080070|13268927.0|6106226|1326892702|11/26/1979|HISPANIC|M|ARS|28-662A1|STOP AT SCENE-DAMAGED VEHICLE|MAJOR CRIMINAL TRAFFIC|04/16/2004|04/10/2004|"|PPD|040688877|CHARLES, BABER/6449        |Dismiss Without Prejudice|04/20/2014|\ ||\ |\ |\ |\ |\ |
3080198|66564.0|6114452|6656401|08/20/1979|HISPANIC|M|ARS|13-3904A|VIOLATION OF PROMISE TO APPEAR|CRIMINAL|04/23/2004|04/23/2004|Phoenix Municipal Court|PMC|||Dismiss Without Prejudice|04/20/2014|\ ||\ |\ |\ |\ |\ |  The first line works the second line is where the code no longer works. This is the raw file.